# Julia - Trim string whitespace and check length

Tags: string, julia

I'm new to Julia and I was wondering if there were any built in functions for trimming string whitespace? I also want to check the length of the string which I know I can do with `length(s) == 0`, but I wondered if there where other built in functions? Thanks!

I'm basically trying to find the Julia equivalent to the following MATLAB code:

```
line = strtrim(line);        
if isempty(line), continue; end % Skip empty lines
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`lstrip` for leading whitespace, `rstrip` for trailing whitespace, `strip`for both.

There is an `isempty` function for julia as well:

```
isempty("")
>> true
```

Perhaps you should check out the Julia docs for other string-related functions (https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/ & https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/strings/)

Answer (score 15):

For the start/end of a string you have

```
lstrip(string)
rstrip(string)
```

if you need to take everything out I recommend you use something like

```
a = "a b c d e f"
join(map(x -> isspace(a[x]) ? "" : a[x], 1:length(a)))
```

because sometimes you can get strings that include some weird whitespaces that wont match `" "` or `' '` [as is shown here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.Unicode.isspace)

**Edit**

```
filter(x -> !isspace(x), a)
```

as suggested by **Fengyang Wang**, is even better

Comment: You should definitely do `filter(x -> !isspace(x), a)` instead of the `map` you wrote.